# Can I add an AngularJS directive as a Jquery Window Content?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, directive, jquery-widgets

I'm trying to add JQuery Window as a widget. This is implemented as a directive and works fine with static content. But I want the content of the jquery window to be another directive. Is it possible?

My directive looks like:

```
function showWidget($timeout, $compile): ng.IDirective {
    var directive = <ng.IDirective>{
        restrict: "E",
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        link: link
    };
 function link(scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attr: ng.IAttributes): void {
 var windowOptions = {
            modalOpacity: 0.5,
            title: "Users",
            content: "<show-users></show-users>", //This is another directive
            checkBoundary: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true,
            maximizable: true,
            minimizable: true,

   //removed for brevity
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> //This is another directive

You would need to look at `$compile` the content and manually linking to the DOM. See : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Note: Not *easy*.